# Tilting modules in a hereditary algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ho.history-overview

1. Who/Which paper was the first to prove or conjecture that the number of tilting modules equals the Catalan number for type $\mathcal{A}$-hereditary algebras?
2. Let $B$ be a tilted algebra of a representation finite hereditary algebra $A$ of Dynkin type $\mathcal{A}$. What is the number of tilting modules in $A$ with endomorphism ring equal to $B$?